# How to display 2 classes JavaScript id in 1 Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am currently stuck on how to display 2 JavaScript ID in 1 Table, I want to display "show list 5, 10, 50" function in the table and also display "export csv, pdf etc" function in the same table, ideally in 1 row.

**Show List View (data-table)**
[image]

**Export View (data-table-export)**
[image]

**My Code as below**

```
<div class="row">
    <table class="stripe hover multiple-select-row data-table nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">Name</th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

$('document').ready(function(){
            $('.data-table').DataTable({
                scrollCollapse: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "datatable-nosort",
                    orderable: false,
                }],
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "language": {
                    "info": "_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search"
                },
            });
            $('.data-table-export').DataTable({
                scrollCollapse: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "datatable-nosort",
                    orderable: false,
                }],
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "language": {
                    "info": "_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search"
                },
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
            });
            var table = $('.select-row').DataTable();
            $('.select-row tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
                else {
                    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }
            });
            var multipletable = $('.multiple-select-row').DataTable();
            $('.multiple-select-row tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
        });
```

Comment: can you make full code in code snippet to understand clearly?

Comment: can you try to change `dom: 'Bfrtip'` to `dom: 'Bfltrip'`